# Set default value of SQL date/time field to current date/time Eastern time zone

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 2012 date/time field default value was set to (GETUTCDATE()).  I've set it to (GETDATE()) but the time is still not Eastern Time Zone (Set on the Windows Server)

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't. Either use UTC everywhere, or use `datetimeoffset`. Assuming some timezone (Eastern, you mean **Eastern European** right? What else could it be?) is as bad as using `varchar` instead of `nvarchar` and hope you never have to store strings in another codepage.

Comment: By the way, if you store local time you'll get unexpected times during daylight changes.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No, I didn't mean Eastern Europe (EET) I meant what I said Eastern Time Zone https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone.  I'm developing a mobile app that pulls data from a server in an Eastern Time Zone.  I think I understand your point.  Will investigate.  Thanks.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Totally understand what you said now.  Both server and mobile date/time should be UTC.  Problem solved.  Thanks!